# Does congruence preserve the reality of matrix eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-congruences

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ have real eigenvalues. Does
\begin{equation}
B = X^TAX
\end{equation}
also have real eigenvalues, for $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and invertible?

Incidentally the $X$ with which I am working is symmetric and positive definite if either of these would be helpful added structure to adapt the question.

Comment: Not necessarily. Take for $X$ a complex, non-real number $z$ times the identity. Then $A$ changes into ${z^2}A$ which has no longer real eigenvalues. But replacing ${X^T}$ by $X^{-1}$ results in a similarity transformation and then the statement is true.

Comment: @Urgje $X$ must be a real matrix.

Comment: All right. Then you can obtain a counterexample by taking for $A$ a diagonal 2x2 matrix and for $X$ some 2x2 matrix with real entries.

Comment: if $A$ is symmetric, the thing is true, and symmetry of $X$ would be irrelevant. This is Sylvester's law of inertia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Counterexample:
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&-3\\ 3&9},
\ B=\pmatrix{1\\ &\frac13}A\pmatrix{1\\ &\frac13}=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ 1&1}.
$$
The eigenvalues of $A$ are $5\pm\sqrt{7}$ and the eigenvalues of $B$ are $1\pm i$.